# Accessing cookies coming from different domain Across different servers

Tags: typescript, express, cookies, nest, nx-workspace

I'm looking to share the cookies received from other domain to be send back in response of my server request. I'm receiving cookie from express server but in my nest server request cookies are not forwarded. It is a cross domain issue.
Need you assistance to configure CORS policy to forward cookies correctly to my FrontEnd Applications
Here attaching link of code for this scenario https://github.com/swapniltech0390/server2server.git

**Scenario**

1. Cookie generated in Express server request and passed
2. Cookie received on API call in Nest server

**Problem :**
Unable to pass the cookie in received from my Express request to frontend through the Nest Server.

Please reach out to me if you need more details.

I tried to set CORS policy and withCredential true but unable to see the cookie in Nest Js server request